# 1) "alt été", and 2) peut + en + infinitive?

Tags: traduction

On my package of frozen salmon fillets, the following text was on the back of the package:

[image]

> We have taken great care to remove all bones from this product,
>   however some bones may remain.
>
> Bien qu'un soin tout particuller alt été pris pour enlever toutes les
>   arêtes, il peut en rester quelques-unes.

I am having trouble translating the French text. Here are some places I have difficulty:

> Bien qu'un soin tout particuller

*Even though a complete care* .. "particuller??" [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/particuller) says that "particuller" has no English translations. **Was this supposed to be "particulier" instead?** But even if it was supposed to be "particulier", I'm not sure what the translation would be, because

*"Even though a complete, specific care.."*

, doesn't sound correct?

> alt été pris

"alt" also doesn't have an English translation. **Is this supposed to be "ait"?**

> il peut en rester quelques-unes

I have finding out what "peut + en + infinitive" means, through google, but I could not find an answer. I haven't ever before encountered "en + infinitive". What does "en + infinitive" generally mean (and is there a way I could have found out the answer myself?).

Comment: Strange. It's supposed to be “ait” and “particulier”. “Tout particulier” is idiomatic French (notice that *tout* is an adverb, not another adjective). A translation won't help to understand its usage. It lies somewhere between “special” and “specific”, and is just a tiny bit reminiscent of a mass-advertising “just for you”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: "tout" seems to be a word that easily confuses learners of French. comments like yours will help me learn its grammatical role as an adverb, as i parse it in a sentence, and also it helps me to sense its unique meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several questions and several answers.

- `particuller`: indeed, as you guessed, it should be `particulier`. `Particulier` is here an adjective that emphazises its noun. In English, is it not correct to say "`We were particularly careful in removing...`"? Here it would be the same idea. And even it is `tout particulier` as a whole (here `tout` does not have a meaning of `complete`). `tout` emphasizes `particulier`, which means `soin` is doubly emphazised (sort of `we were really really particularly careful, I swear`). It is called marketing ^^.
- Indeed, it is `ait`. It is subjunctive of `avoir`. Subjunctive is needed after `bien que`.
- `en` is here a pronoun, that means `of them`. `Il peut en rester quelques-unes` => `Il peut rester quelques-unes [de ces arêtes]`. I think your difficulty was that you sought a meaning for `pouvoir + en`. There is none ! `en` is not related to `pouvoir`, here.

Comment: idioms are so difficult for me as a language learner to learn! so thanks for this. also, i did not know that "en" could apply, simply using its usually meaning as a pronoun, to infinitives, but now i do. really helpful answer, tanks.